# Ударение в слове сидор (вещмешок)

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Каким должно быть ударение в слове ***сидор*** (вещмешок)

Answer (score 2):

Словари на [**Грамоте.ру**](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80&all=x) говорят, что ударение в этом слове падает на первый слог:

***си́дор.***